# externally forcing python environment isolation in CI builds

Tags: python, jenkins

Our data pipeline runs scheduled jobs via Jenkins on a pool of autoscaled build workers.  Some scripts use python 2.x, some use 3.x.  (I'm not a pythonista, so please forgive if I'm asking something dumb...)

I was looking at a build failure, and it was complaining about some "egg link" that had a mismatched path.  I was alarmed to discover that it seems that the builds share some context globally, as the cited path (/usr/local/lib/python/dist-packages/xxx) referred to a totally unrelated project that just happened to have been built on the same worker!

I see that I can wrap builds with a pyenv or virtualenv or something, but there are hundreds of jobs, and it seems kind of crazy to me that builds need to "opt in" to isolation.  I want the CI server to enforce it by default.

I can rework the build workers to run on each job as an ephermeral Docker process, but python and Jenkins have been around forever, and I don't feel I should need to go to that length.  What's the old-school way that CI builds forced python build isolation?

Comment: You will have to deal with virtual environments or with docker. I would take the second approach for sure.
There are other alternatives like Bazel but it is probably overkill for your situation.